# Mathematics simple example

Tags: java, math, floating-point, jls

I am trying to do simple math. a=5, b=a/2 &(round up), which has to be 5/2 = 3 when I round up , c=b-a, 3-5=2. my question when I divide 5/2 and round up I got 2 instead of 3 for b. can some one help me how I can round up and get 3? Thanks

```
int a=5;

int b=(int)Math.ceil(a/2);

int c=b-a;


System.out.println(b);

System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: Read up on integer arithmetic in Java.

Comment: @haylu Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 4):

you should use floating-point value of `2` instead of integer in this line:

```
int b = (int) Math.ceil(a / 2f);//also you can use "2.0" or "2d" instead of "2f"
```

your version uses `int` division (which produces `int` value of `2`) and `2f` constant forces to use floating-point division and promote `a` value to `float` (after it division produces `float` value of `2.5`)

It is possible because of JLS spec for [Multiplicative Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17):

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2)

And that is how [numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) works for `int` and `float` division operands in our case:

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>   If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>   Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.

Comment: `(a/2d)` should also work, to enforce double division .

Comment: Nit: it's not `float` division, it is floating-point division (since `2.0` is a `double`). Similarly, `2.5` is a `double`, not a `float`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, you're right

Comment: it works.Thanks @Cootri

Comment: glad it helped! Welcome to the Stackoverflow and not forget to mark an answer as accepted to close this question  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a little trick to get things faster:

```
int b =(a + 1) / 2;
```

Since you are dividing with 2, in case the number is odd with + 1, you'll get exact value for upper rounding. And if number is even with + 1 rounding will give the half of it as expected.

**EDIT**

Or in general, if you want to calculate  `Math.ceil(a / b)` you can do it with following formula :  `(a + b - 1) / b`, assuming a and b being positive.

Comment: More generally, to round up `a / b`, you add `b - 1` to the numerator: `(a + b - 1) / b` (provided `a` and `b` are positive).

Comment: Yes, that generalizes this issue. Thank you for pointing this out.